# Has there been any philosophical interpretation (or application) of Stone lattices?

Tags: logic

[Stone lattices](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Stone_lattice)/algebras are Heyting (i.e. intuitionistic) lattices in which both laws of De Morgan hold, or [equivalently](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/De+Morgan+Heyting+algebra), Heyting lattices in which also ~p \/ ~~p = 1.

While these have been studied a fair bit by mathematicians (perhaps because their structure is "nice" so a lot of results can be proven about them), **have there been any philosophical interpretations or applications of this class of (Stone) lattices**?

For example, Dunn's ["kite of negations"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20016717?seq=1) (which has quite a few variants) never seems to mentions these Stone lattices, although it does mention the both intuitionistic and De Morgan lattices (which are a stronger version of Stone's, meaning that additionally ~~p == p in the latter) as being on "separate branches" so to speak:

[image]

(Or maybe I'm missing something and Stone lattices the are "on the kite picture" by some equivalent axioms?)

I see from the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_logic) on superintuitionistic (aka intermediate) logic that the answer is probably yes, although under names that don't refer to Stone (as mathematicians do):

> (KC, Jankov's logic, De Morgan logic[2]): IPC + ¬¬p ∨ ¬p.

De Morgan's name has been overloaded quite a bit, apparently... Although that's technically an answer, maybe someone can say a bit more than that one liner, i.e. what kind of interpretations has it been given.